# Count variable and add a new column

Tags: sas

i want to count variables by class and num :

```
 id  class num   
  3   FE     351
  3   FE     351
  3   FE     352
```

How can i create the new variable like the table below

```
  id   class    num    count
  3     FE       351    2
  3     FE       351    2
  3     FE       352    1
```

Comment: is `ID` part of the group?  or it is only count by `class` and `num`?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the `ID` is not part of the group based on the question.  If this is not the case, then add it appropriately.

First create a tables of counts.

```
proc sql noprint;
create table counts as
   select class,
          num,
          count(*) as count
   from have
   group by class, num;
quit;
```

Then rejoin to the main table

```
proc sql noprint;
create table want as
select a.id,
       a.class,
       a.num,
       b.count
   from have as a
     left join
        counts as b
     on a.class = b.class 
      and 
        a.num = b.num;
quit;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in one simple `SQL` statement:

```
proc sql noprint;
    create table want as
    select id, class, num, count(num) as count
    from have
    group by num;
quit;
```